# Estimates and standard errors for non-linear combinations of regression coefficients

Tags: regression, time-series, stata

I have the econometric model
$$
 y_t= (1-b_0)(c + b_1x1_t + b_2x2_t + ...) + b_0*y_{t-1}  
$$
$$
=(1-b_0)c + (1-b_0)(b_1x1_t)+... + b_0*y_{t-1}  
$$
I estimate the model in the OLS form
$$
y_t=\beta_0c +\beta_1 x_t + ... + \beta_2y_{t-1}
$$
where for example
$$
b_1=\beta_1/(1-\beta_2)
$$
how do I recover from the OLS estimates the $b$ variables of interest? I am currently using Stata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get nonlinear combinations of coefficients like this, along with the their standard errors via the delta method:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. reg price mpg weight i.foreign, coefl

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 70)        =     23.29
       Model |   317252881         3   105750960   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   317812515        70  4540178.78   R-squared       =    0.4996
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.4781
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2130.8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.  Legend
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |    21.8536  _b[mpg]
      weight |   3.464706  _b[weight]
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |    3673.06  _b[1.foreign]
       _cons |  -5853.696  _b[_cons]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. nlcom (b:_b[mpg]/(1-_b[weight])) (c:_b[weight]/_b[1.foreign]), post

           b:  _b[mpg]/(1-_b[weight])
           c:  _b[weight]/_b[1.foreign]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           b |  -8.866617   28.39079    -0.31   0.755    -64.51155    46.77832
           c |   .0009433   .0001725     5.47   0.000     .0006052    .0012813
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test b=c

 ( 1)  b - c = 0

           chi2(  1) =    0.10
         Prob > chi2 =    0.7548
```

The `coefl` option in `regress` makes it easier to see what the coefficients are named by Stata. You can also add the `nocons` option, which I've neglected to do. The `post` option in `nlcom` stores the estimation vector and variance–covariance matrix, making it easy to do hypothesis tests on these functions of coefficients.

You should also think about patching up your standard errors by using a time-series command like `newey` that can deal with serially correlated errors. The standard OLS assumptions about the errors are unlikely to hold here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on STATA, but if you feed STATA a left hand side variable $y_t$ and the regressors, $x$ and $y_{t-1}$, and tell it to estimate parameters with OLS, the outputted parameters $\beta_0, \beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ will probably fit in the linear model in this way, 
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 y_{t-1}. 
$$
That is I don't think that STATA ouputs the term $\beta_0 c$ as the intercept unless you tell it explicitly to do so.

So given the above linear model it's easy to retrieve the $b_i$'s, since
$$
\beta_0 = \left(1-b_0\right)c  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad c=\frac{\beta_0}{1-b_0}
$$
$$
\beta_1 = \left(1-b_0\right)b_1  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad b_1=\frac{\beta_1}{1-b_0}
$$
and the $b_0$ estimate is simply the OLS estimate of $\beta_2$, which we can just plug into the two equations above.